# Solution verification trying to prove that $l_1^{*}=l_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to proove that $l_1^{*}=l_{\infty}$. For this I have defined the aplication

$\Lambda:l_{\infty}\longrightarrow l_{1}^{*}$ such that $y\in l_{\infty}\longmapsto \Lambda_{y}:l_1 \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ where $\Lambda_{y}(x)=\displaystyle\sum y_nx_n$

We need to prove that $\Lambda$ is well-defined, $\Lambda$ is lineal and $\Lambda$ is an surjective isometry. My problem is in the last point.

Is easy to see that $||\Lambda_y||\leq ||y||$ so I want to show that there exists $x\in c_0$ verifying that $\Lambda_y(x)=||y||$. For this I defined $x=(x_n)$ such that $x_n=\frac{sup(y)}{y_n 2^n}$ if $y_n \neq0$ and $x_n=0$ inf other case. With this we have:

$|\Lambda_y(x)-||y|||=|\displaystyle\sum y_n x_n-sup(y)|=|\displaystyle\sum\frac{sup(y)}{ 2^n}-sup(y)|=0$

So $||\Lambda_y||=||y||$. Is this correct?